# AS2: MovieClip tracing wrong height

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I have a masked movieclip which contains nothing but static text inserted from the IDE (not programatically).

In the IDE it states this movieclips height to be 332.25, however when I trace the movieclips `_height` property it returns 327.3.

This is causing my scrollbar code to mess up as it is not scrolling down far enough. It is also not a one off thing, every block of text I make in the IDE exhibits this behaviour.

Does anyone know why this could be occuring?

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour could happen when using text set as dynamic text and without embedding it in the movie.
Did you tried to embed the font?

Comment: Just for test, try to break apart (Ctrl+B) TWICE the text and see the result.